# Is it possible to use Autoit to operate on a Remote Desktop?

Tags: automated-tests, autoit, remote-desktop

I need to automate actions I do on a Remote Desktop. The au3recoder (which comes with Autoit) doesn't seem to record anything on the RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Autoit works on RDP machines if you execute the file on that machine. If you want to use it from your own PC over the RDP connection that could get difficult.

1. You can't detect windows over RDP what makes most of the AutoIt functions useless.
2. You could click on positions with MouseClick(). It's not the most elegant version but it works for little things.
3. The Au3 Recorder never worked for my anyways, so you could also hardcode it yourself.

I recomend that you copy a file to your RDP machine to use all AutoIt functions.

Comment: when I have the AU3Recorder installed in the main machine and then I login via the remote desktop to another vm, the AU3Recorder doesnt pickup anything, I have also tried to 'run("notepad.exe")' on the Remote vm but in vain so my question is if AutoIt works on a Remote Desktop..I figure it doesn't.

Comment: It does work for sure. Maybe you have another problem but i only work on RDP-machines and it works perfectly fine like i would be local.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible.
And you could use most of the "AutoIt" functions because they are C++ functions which windows have them all.
The most accurate way to do it is to use CMD through AutoIt to get most of the informations.
However the most elegant way would be using PowerShell.